# Process files in a directory with jquery and php - fetch status and update progressbar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to show dynamically the current state (image x of y) using jquery and jquery ui (progressbar, ajax?)

I already know how to read a directory, the files and also save them to the database.

How can i fetch the status of the request and update the progressbar?

Comment: That's lots you want to do :)

Comment: If you show us some code, we might be able to help you. This I can do nothing with.

Comment: You write and then debug the code until it works

Comment: There are a ton of questions here. You need to know how to read the files in a directory with PHP, how to save them to a database, how to keep track of the progress, how to poll the server with jQuery for that progress, and how to update a jQuery UI progress bar. The answer to each of those is considerably in-depth, and I think everyone will expect a code sample.

Comment: I know how to read a directory with ph and the files and also how to save them. the problem is the function to fetch the state (image x of y)

Comment: now its less what i want to do, its just how i can fetch the status and update the progressbar

Comment: used smartupdater and jquery ui progressbar and process image after image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this with smartupdater and some php and jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

"Image x of y" means that you would like to implement "paging". In other words, when you have image 3 displayed and user clicks next, you want the image 4 to be loaded. This as other said, is a lot. But you can send the Id (any unique number) of the current image to the server, find the next image, send it back to the browser (this could be all done in ajax), and then update the progress bar based on the percentage of the position of the current image in number of all images.

Comment: no, a progressbar showing the current state of the php file (now processing image x of y)

Comment: In that case need "polling" regularly, or something like web sockets (server-sent events).

Comment: is there a tutorial or could you give me a link to an example? dont know if it is this what you mean

Comment: well, the php script normally is running a while statement, can i fetch the current state (like processing image 1 of 20 now) with jquery and how? thats what i want